# grep options in variable with spaces

Tags: shell, grep

I am trying to use a variable to store `grep`'s options:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -xe

GREP_OPTS="-e \"test this\""
echo "I want to test this." | grep $GREP_OPTS
```

Output:

```
+ GREP_OPTS=-e "test this"
+ echo I want to test this.
+ grep -e "test this"
grep: this": No such file or directory
```

how can I make this work?

Comment: FYI, `set -e` is... err, let's say *controversial*. I'd suggest avoiding its use until answers to the exercises in [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises) come to you off the top of your head (should you still *want* to use it, after knowing how unreliable, inconsistent and unintuitive its behavior is in practice). See also https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/, comparing different shells' implementations and how they differ incompatibly from each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Word-Splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) is occurring on your `GREP_OPTS="-e \"test this\""` resulting in the command being

```
grep -e '"test' 'this"'
```

Resulting in the exact error:

```
grep: this": No such file or directory
```

(of course there is no file named `"this\""`)

See [BashFAQ-50 - I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

In order to prevent word splitting use an array for options instead of trying to use a single variable, e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -xe

GREP_OPTS=(-e "test this")
echo "I want to test this." | grep "${GREP_OPTS[@]}"
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash grepopts.sh
+ GREP_OPTS=(-e "test this")
+ echo 'I want to test this.'
+ grep -e 'test this'
I want to test this.
```

Let me know if you have further questions.